# No database selected help me solve this

Tags: php

hey everyone what's wrong with this :( i get no database selected .. what seems to be the problem ? damn i can't get this right.

```
    <?php
require_once('db.php');

function getLanguage() {
    global $db;
    global $conn;


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books.languages ORDER BY name ASC";
    $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    $rs = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
    $tot_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);
    if($tot_rows > 0){




?>
```

Comment: here's my db.php

<?php 
$hostname = "localhost";
$db = "books";
$username = "root";
$password = "kel";
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);



?>

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is no database is selected (didn't I see that in your question ?)

Where is your call to `mysql_select_db ( string $database_name [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`?

It should be after the `connect`.

```
$db = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db("your_database_name");
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
```

(obviously you should have error checking too...)

Comment: when i replace $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); with  mysql_select_db($db, $conn); 

i get this : Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given
mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given

Comment: Don't replace it. You need both!

Comment: my $username, $password, $hostname are not working maybe my db.php dosen't do a thing. here's my code 

<?php 
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "kel";
$db = "books";

$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

?>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following will help? I am using MySQLi as MySQL is deprecated.

db.php

```
<?php    
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    $DB_NAME = 'database';
    $DB_HOST = 'host';
    $DB_USER = 'username';
    $DB_PASS = 'password';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }
?>
```

Then use the following to query your database.

```
<?php
    require_once('db.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
    $rs = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    if($rs->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Do Something  
    }
    }
    else {
    echo 'NO RESULTS';  
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: thanks , but i tried it still not working though